# use an image as icon in IconButton - ChakraUI

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

i want to use a .png file inside `IconButton`, but
setting `icon="/image.png` or `src="/image.png` does not work
How do i pass an image as the icon for the IconButton component in chakraUI?

Answer (score 4):

You can nest the `<Image>` component inside the `<IconButton>` component like this:

```
<IconButton icon={<Image src="/image.png" />} />
```

Answer (score -1):

i ask a bit early
so i fixed this by creating an `imageElement = React.CreateElement("img", {src="/image.png"})` the passing it into the `icon={imageElement}` of `IconButton`

Answer (score -2):

Yoyoy any image no create react stuff

import ListIcon, Image from Chakraui blah blah

<ListIcon as={Image} src={`${url OR API call}`}/>